# What is a good method to determine when an entities data has been changed on the database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, concurrency

Say, using Entity Framework, I have retrieved an Entity from the database. Is there any way to check subsequently that the same specific Entity has changed in the database by another user?

The method I have used previously (in WinForm applications) was to:

- Save Entity to the db
- Add an entry to a Transactions table with the Entity type, Unique identifier, and datetime changed
- When refreshing the same Entity, check for rows in the Transaction table subsequent to the current user's Save.
- If an entry is found, act accordingly (reload Entity from database, block Editing, Save conflicts etc depending on why I am checking for a change).

The reasons I want to do this is to:

- Avoid reloading an entire set of Entities and just refresh the Entities that have changed
- Check for concurrency conflicts on Save
- Resolve concurrency conflicts based when Editing began. To do this I need to make an entry in the Transactions table when a user *begins* editing and update the same Transaction table row when the user saves / cancels.

Does this method seem right? Are the reasons for doing this even correct at all? And perhaps there's already functionality to do this that I haven't been able to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder why you don't use one of the more standard ways of optimistic concurrency. EF has [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx) for this. I think a separate Transactions table only adds complexity because you always have to explicitly maintain entries in that table while doing CRUD operations on the main entities. What happens when a user begins editing and creates a "locking" entry in the Transactions table, but then crashes? Wouldn't an exclusive lock on the record in the database be appropriate here (i.e. *pessimistic* locking).

You can also use this approach to check for intermediate changes, because you can execute a light query on the timestamp or version column.

Comment: Sorry, check on Edit was badly worded, have edited the question. The problem I have with EF ObjectContext.Refresh and the unit of work pattern is: If there are sets of "reference" objects I use throughout the application, and they don't change that often, why reload the lot of them from the database? Also, using a timestamp / version column is surely less efficient than storing the information in a separate table. But ultimately, you're right, unless I have a good reason I should be using the standard EF concurrency rather than roll my own.

Comment: You would normally fetch such immutable reference data from the database by a short-lived ObjectContext, after which they live in your application independently. As for your second point: less efficient? An update is on one record in stead of two. Anyway, yes, a DBMS is probably better at transaction management then you and I are.

Comment: Heh, but the problem is that the reference data is not -completely- immutable... and the doubling of the update work is more than offset by multiple clients only reading one transaction table to determine changes. Given that the gains achieved by managing your own concurrency hardly outweighs the benefits of using a widely used DBMS, I'm marking your answer as correct. Thanks for your comments.