# Locking with EF Code First

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, concurrency, ef-code-first, locking

I have a table that holds information about cars (let's call it tbl_incoming_car). That table has a non-unique column named 'customer_number', that shows the number of cars that have get into the system so far. The same car can get in and out lot of times, but this is registered only once.

So, when a new car gets in, I need to get the number of the last one, increment it, and then save it as the 'customer_number' of the new car.

I know that the easiest way would be to have a separated table for cars, have the 'customer_number' there, and register the ins and outs in other table, but this is just a silly example to expose the situation. So there is no point in discuss that the approach is wrong, I know that already :)

As I said, every time a new car enters into the system, I have to get the latest added row, get the 'customer_number', increment it and save it as an atomic operation. Other application instances could try to do the same, and the DB must hold requests for the last added row during the "creation task".

I thought that I would be able of doing it by setting the isolation level to serializable, but I think it won't prevent from reading the last row, but from inserting the new one. So it looks like locking is the solution. I have tried using a static object as Monitor in the code, and it works fine, but of course it is limited to the same application domain, I need something at the DB level.

I don't think there is anything in EF to set a lock on the DB, so which would be the best way of set up a lock on a table and release it later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, this is the best way I have came up with:

```
    public void SetTransactionLock(String resourceName)
    {
        Ensure.IsNotNull(resourceName, "resourceName");

        String command = String.Format(
        @"declare @result int;
          EXEC @result = sp_getapplock '{0}', 'Exclusive', 'Transaction', 10000 
          IF @result < 0
            RAISERROR('ERROR: cannot get the lock [{0}] in less than 10 seconds.', 16, 1);",resourceName);

        base.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
    }

    public void ReleaseTransactionLock(String resourceName)
    {
        Ensure.IsNotNull(resourceName, "resourceName");
        String command = String.Format("EXEC sp_releaseapplock '{0}';",resourceName);
        base.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
    }
```

Since there is no built-in way in EF, I added these two methods to my data layer, and I use them to declare that "critical section" where only one concurrent operation is allowed.

You can use it in a try finally block.

Comment: did you test it? I do get exception on ReleaseTransactionLock if anything is executed in between, and the reason for that is that EF runs sp_resetconnection before every query, which releases every app lock it obtains, so the lock is not really held anymore

Comment: I posted my own solution, see if you like it better

Comment: sp_resetconnection is called when a connection is retrieved from the connection pool in order to make it ready for use. Usually, in my use case I was holding the connection until release, that is, I acquired the lock, do operations, save and release. So it is working fine.

Comment: maybe we are using different versions... In my case (EF 6.0), connection from DbContext keeps getting reset/reused, so unless you clone it, lock doesn't stay.

Answer (score 1):

Serializable actually does solve this. Serializable means that transactions behave as if they all took a global database X-lock. As if only one transaction executed at the same time.

This is also true for inserts. The locks will be taken in such as way as to prevent inserts at the wrong places.

You might not achieve deadlock-freedom though. Still worth a try.

Comment: I tried but I got problems with deadlocks. I am not very sure about how serializable works. For example, if I do a SELECT to get the last row before an INSERT, are future rows that could appear in the SELECT prevented from be read? Because the application read the last row, process the value, and then save the new row. My understanding is that "serializable" would prevent the app from inserting the row, but not from reading the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Using REPEATABLE READ isolation level can aquire lock at the moment you execute the SELECT command. How I don´t know then SELECT command to retrieve the last line, maybe it won´t work. The way you execute the SELECT change the way SQL Locks Lines/Indexes/Tables.

The best aprroach would be to execute a stored procedure. EF makes some roundtrips between the database and application that will increase the lock time and impact your application performance.

Maybe you could use a trigger to make the update after the insert.

Comment: Right, but we are trying to get by without SP till we have clear all we have to do (dynamic requirements, you know :P). At the moment we go through big cycles of refactoring, and the SP would get in the way.

Comment: EF won´t give you much options to control transaction over SQL. In the past I used EF only, but for performance, I was forced to break the rule. In the entire app, whe just have about 5 SP, for very specific performance intensive data transactions.

Answer (score 1):

EF works with C# `TransactionScope`.

In the past, I have been solving similar problem like this:

```
 using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (var db = new DbContext())
            {
                db.Set<Car>().Add(newCar);
                db.SaveChanges();
                // newCar.Id has value here, but record is locked for read until ts.Complete()

                newCar.CustomerNumber = db.Set<Car>().Max(car => car.CustomerNumber) + 1;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            ts.Complete();
        }
```

The line `db.Set<Car>().Max(car => car.CustomerNumber)` in any concurrent tasks will have to wait, because it needs to have access to all records, you can check this by adding breakpoint before ts.Complete() and trying to execute `Select max(CustomerNumber) from dbname.dbo.Cars` while code is paused on that line. Query will complete when you resume code and ts completes.

Of course, this only works if your example is good enough description for the real scenario you have, but it should be easy to adapt to your needs.

See [transactions in ef on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: See that although there is a transaction, I need to block other threads from reading data, what cannot be done with a simple transaction. The transaction in "serializable" isolation level, would prevent other threads from adding a row that match a given predicate, but not from reading it.

Comment: I don't understand. The default transaction, like this one here will prevent other threads from reading the row that is being added (newCar), and if you only insert records with this method, then they will wait until transaction is complete to be able to read that record, and add a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Solution previously mentioned on this thread may not be universally applicable, because EF runs `sp_resetconnection` before any SQL operation, so when you run anything invoiving SQL on the DbContext, it essentially releases the lock you were supposed to be holding.

What I came up with is: you need to clone SqlConnection before obtaining the lock, and hold on to this connection until you are ready to release:

```
public class SqlAppLock {
    DbConnection connection;
    public SqlAppLock(DbContext context, string resourceName)
    {
        ... (test arguments for null, etc)
        connection = (DbConnection)(context.Database.Connection as ICloneable).Clone();
        connection.Open();

        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_getapplock";
        ... (set up parameters)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int result = (int)cmd.Parameters["@result"].Value;
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not acquire lock on resource");
        }
    }
```

and then to release, could release the lock using `sp_releaseapplock`, or simply Dispose() the connection

Answer (score 0):

EF supports the SQL timeStamp also known as rowversion dataType.

This allows you to  perform updates using optimistic locking.
The framework does that for you if the fields are declared properly.
Essentially :

**UPDATE where ID=ID  SET Customer_number to X+1**
becomes
**Update where ID=ID and Rowversion = rowversion Set Customer_number =X+1**

So if the row has changed since it was loaded in thread X, you get an error.
You can reload and try again or take what ever action is appropriate in your scenario.

form more info see, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx

and this SO post

[What is a good method to determine when an entities data has been changed on the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279653/what-is-a-good-method-to-determine-when-an-entities-data-has-been-changed-on-the/7283499#7283499)

Comment: I am talking about inserting, not updating. Nobody is going to update any row, this is just inserting rows.

Comment: how do you get an lock inserting? then the source of the key is the issue.  A DB generated Key or Guid would work.  What are you using to generate the "unique" key.  Sounds strange to me.

Comment: using pesimistic concurrency, as I am going to post now

Comment: Ok I understand now what you are trying to do, and it should work. I would personally try an optimistic lock pattern before Pessimistic locking for that problem.   eg table LastNumber, with key "LastNumberCateegory" , with a field Lastnumbre and a concurrency rowversion field.

Comment: btw, its not clear from your sample code if you intend to place the lock update unlock inside a transaction. Example commit/rollback usage if you  go with sp_getapplock.     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx